# Installing Adobe Illustrator CC via Wine (PlayOnLinux)

Tags: wine, playonlinux, adobe, winetricks

I am running a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 dist trying to install Adobe Illustrator CC (64-bit). The following image below illustrates where it jams in the installation process when installing via PlayOnLinux.

[image]

I've been reading [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27594) that it doesn't seem to work on 64-bit systems. I have PlayOnLinux and Winetricks installed also. Anyone know how to get around this issue?

I can't seem to install via Winetricks eaither due to the fact that illustrator will not install onto an XP version of wine (winetricks).

Comment: Are you using the manual installation process under PlayOnLinux? Or the "pre coocked" receipe?

Answer (score 1):

Be patient - it does install, but it appears to hang. It took about 20min for me.

Comment: I have Illustrator CS6 working Super Great...... but it is correct that Illustrator CC 2015 does not work. it's weird because Photoshop CC 2015 works great tho.